# Mov file playback error using MLT Melt on OSX

Tags: macos, melt, mlt

I'm trying to playback a Mov file on OSX using the command:

```
$melt MVI_3001.mov
```

However, there's a momentary flash and the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

What does this mean? How can I playback the Mov files?

Answer (score 0):

It means SDL is not working in your build of melt. I do not know why; there is not enough information. It could be that FFmpeg was built against SDL2, but MLT was built against SDL1.2. The build of melt that comes with [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org) works (/Applications/Shotcut.app/Contents/MacOS/melt).